# creating a directory using docker swarm compose/yaml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is there a way to create a directory on the local file system via yaml file if it does not exist? 
I currently am mounting a dir from my local file sys inside the container and it works. But if the dir on the file system does not exist, container launch fails as the dir cannot be mounted. How can I make this as seamless as possible and embed the dir creation logic in the swarm yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `docker-compose` doesn't permit this, you probably have to do this by hand.

But you could also use an automation tool like [puppet](https://puppet.com/) or [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to handle such step to deploy your application and create the appropriate directories and set up your servers.

Here is how your tasks could look like in an [ansible playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example) to deploy a simple app and create a directory to mount your containers volumes on for instance :

```
- name: copy docker content
  copy:
    src: /path/to/app_src
    dest: /path/to/app_on_server

- name: create directory for volume
  file:
    name: /path/to/mountpoint
    state: directory

- name: start containers
  shell: docker-compose up -d --build
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/app_on_server
```

(Note that this snippet is here to provide a general idea of the concept, you'd probably have to set up [become directives](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html), permissions, ownership, software installation and many other steps very specific to your application)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be, that you get the `Dockerfile` for example from the official [Nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/c8bfb9b5260d4ad308deac5343b73b027f684375/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile) image and add an additional `RUN mkdir /my/folder` to it.

Afterwards you build your own Docker image for the Nginx via `docker build .`. Then you have a clean image which contains what you need based on the official source.